# Swift redraw view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a theme class with a few fields.

Background color, font color and element color.

This class also has few static variations of those

```
class Themes {
    static let defaultTheme = Themes(topColor: "5856D6",bottomColor: "C644FC",elementColor: "1F1F21",fontColor: "2B2B2B", name:"one")
    static let defaultTheme1 = Themes(topColor: "5AD427",bottomColor: "FFDB4C",elementColor: "1F1F21",fontColor: "2B2B2B", name:"two")
    static let defaultTheme2 = Themes(topColor: "FB2B69",bottomColor: "FF5B37",elementColor: "1F1F21",fontColor: "2B2B2B", name:"three")
    static let defaultTheme3 = Themes(topColor: "52EDC7",bottomColor: "5AC8FB",elementColor: "1F1F21",fontColor: "2B2B2B", name:"four")
    static let defaultTheme4 = Themes(topColor: "5AD427",bottomColor: "FFDB4C",elementColor: "1F1F21",fontColor: "2B2B2B", name:"five")

    let topColor:UIColor
    let bottomColor:UIColor
    let elementColor:UIColor
    let fontColor:UIColor
}
```

My view controller loads the first one by default.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.initView(ThemeManagement.sharedInstance.getTheme())

}
```

I have a button which changes the theme by going to the `next` one of the defaults and looping around back to `defaultTheme` after `defaultTheme4`

The original run through inside initView is setting the view correctly. But each pass does not update the view. Despite the log messages of the function being printed.

```
func initView(objectColor : Themes){
    println("initing theme "+objectColor.name+"\n"+objectColor.topColor.debugDescription)
    let background = CAGradientLayer().gradient(objectColor.topColor, bottomColorCode: objectColor.bottomColor)
    background.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(background, atIndex: 0)


    codes.delegate = self
    codes.placeholder = "####"
    codes.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    codes.font = Themes.defaultThemeWithFontSize(.H2)
    codes.textColor = objectColor.fontColor

    segments.tintColor = objectColor.elementColor

    segments.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Male), forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
    segments.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.VenusMars), forSegmentAtIndex: 1)
    segments.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Female), forSegmentAtIndex: 2)
    var font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(fontsize/2);
    var attr = NSDictionary(object: font, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
    segments.setTitleTextAttributes(attr as [NSObject : AnyObject], forState:UIControlState.Normal)

    acceptButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(fontsize)
    acceptButton.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(FontAwesome.ArrowCircleORight), forState: .Normal)
    acceptButton.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    workedButton.setTitle("yes", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    workedButton.tintColor = objectColor.fontColor
    workedButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    workedButton.titleLabel?.font = Themes.defaultThemeWithFontSize(.H2)
    workedButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.333, green:0.937, blue:0.796, alpha: 0.2)

    didntWorkButton.setTitle("no", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    didntWorkButton.tintColor = objectColor.fontColor
    didntWorkButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    didntWorkButton.titleLabel?.font = Themes.defaultThemeWithFontSize(.H2)
    didntWorkButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.333, green:0.937, blue:0.796, alpha: 0.2)


    locationButton.setTitle("Current Location", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    locationButton.tintColor = objectColor.fontColor
    locationButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    locationButton.titleLabel?.font = Themes.defaultThemeWithFontSize(.H3)

    didItWork.text = "Did it work?"
    didItWork.font = Themes.defaultThemeWithFontSize(.H2)
    didItWork.textColor = objectColor.fontColor

    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Do I have to do something else to get the background `layer` to update and the font colors to change?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to determine what you are doing and what is going wrong. What does `/* bunch of UI stuff */` do?

Comment: I was trying to keep it short and clean. But I've updated it to include everything there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by this

```
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(background, atIndex: 0)
```

every time you insert a new background layer **behind** the old one so you won't see it.

and change the tintColor of a view won't change the view's color immediately so try to change it's textColor direacly

**Edit by cripto**

The answer above is correct. I just wanted to add my solution to it.

I simply keep a reference to the layer and remove it as long as its not null. This guarantees that I can set it on the first pass and change it every time there after.

```
    if((backgroundLayer) != nil){
        backgroundLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()

    }
    backgroundLayer = CAGradientLayer().gradient(objectColor.topColor, bottomColorCode: objectColor.bottomColor)
    backgroundLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(backgroundLayer, atIndex: 0)
```

Comment: Also all of the `fontColor` attributes in your themes are the same, so you shouldn't expect to see anything different.

Comment: I figured that when you asked me to provide more details. Just didnt update the post properly.